# Existence of graph automorphism with certain property, without enumerating the automorphism group.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a directed graph, $A, B \subseteq V(G)$ be two subsets of its vertices, and $S$ be a generating set of its automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

How can we determine whether there is a morphism $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ with $\phi(v) \in B$ for all $v \in A$?

Is it possible to use $S$ to determine that, without exhaustively constructing $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$?

Comment: How large are $A$ and $B$? If $A$ is small then enumerating all images of $A$ may be faster than enumerating $G$.

Comment: This seems a sensible question. Why have two people voted to close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a problem in computation in permutation groups - the graph is not relevant to the computation.

You could compute the stabilizer $X$ of the set $A$  in ${\rm Aut}(G)$, and then find a (right) transversal $T$ of $X$ in ${\rm Aut}(G)$. Then the images of $A$ under the elements in $T$ are the distinct images of $A$ under ${\rm Aut}(G)$, so you can just check whether any of these images lie in $B$. (Of course, if $X$ is trivial then you will end up enumerating the elements of ${\rm Aut}(G)$.)

I would recommend doing this computation in GAP or Magma (which use right actions).

Comment: Thank you, @Derek-Holt. Is there some name for the images of $A$ under the elements in $T$? I am asking you this because I want to create a second question about this topic, and it would be very useful to know the name of this relation between a set of elements and the distinct sets of elements it can become through the actions of the group.

Comment: The set of images of $A$ under the elements of $T$ is the same as the set of images of $A$ under the action of $G$, which is the orbit of $A$ under the action of $G$.

Comment: Thank you! "Orbit" was the name I was looking for.